# How to implement proxy rotation when scraping urls with google search

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, google-search

Currently I am using 'googlesearch' python library and a function to do google searches and store the websites inside a list, this is my code:

```
from googlesearch import search

def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls


google_urls = get_urls('future', 5000, 'it') #future is the keyword.
```

When I run this code i get this error:

HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

How can i handle it?
How can i implement a proxy rotation considering my code?
Thanks. If you have a more efficient way, i'm happy to hear it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [googlesearch library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374814/googlesearch-library-for-python)

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question  is allready answered in [googlesearch library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374814/googlesearch-library-for-python).

==> dublicate.

You can also have a look at the [Documentation](https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch)

Comment: Hello, this does not solve my problem

Comment: Did you try out the answer provided?

Comment: I don't find the file "googlesearch_settings.py". It would be perfect if you could provide sample code or more explaination of how to do it. Thanks